How to download a video including sound?
I need to download a video from a server (API). Right now I have something like this:
def download_video(url, where_to_store):
   response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
   if response.status_code == 200:
      with open(f"{local_video_path}", "wb") as file:
           for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024*1024):
               file.write(chunk)
   else:
      return response.status_code

This code downloads the video alright, but does not include the sound. I have tried this with different videos but with the same result. Do I have to download the sound seperately?
Many thanks!

I don't see anything wrong with your code. requests does not have any logic that would allow it to strip video from sound. Use e.g. this link to verify that your code works: https://sample-videos.com/video321/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_2mb.mp4 If you can share the actual URL you have problems with, that could help us in resolving this. Or shout if the file from the URL I provided comes without sound.

Audio is embedded in the mp4 file, just like other video formats.  It's most likely a problem with your playback device.  Maybe as simple as forgetting you have headphones plugged in the audio jack.
